# Save values in a matrix using rbind

Tags: r

In R I have 2 functions `a` and `b`. `a` takes 1 integer and returns 1 integer while `b` takes one integer and returns 1,2 or 3 integers. So for example:

```
a(1)=6 and b(1)= 3 4
and a(2)=10 and b(2) = 2.
```

Now I want to save functions values of only `b` so I create this loop but it does not work in R.

```
u=matrix(,)
for(j in 1:100) {
u[,j] = rbind( a(j), b(j) ) 
}
```

R says `'error: subscript out of bounds'`.

I simply want a matrix that have functions-values of `b` so by typing `u` I should get this

```
3 4
2
...
```

Comment: Depending on what you want to do after, it should be easier to use a `list`.

Comment: I want to count / compare the 'b values' with other datasets.

Comment: It's unclear what you're trying to do. You say you want to save values of `b`, but you rbind `a(j)` to `b(j)`.... And generally, lists are easier with changing dimensions.

Comment: `l <- lapply(1:100, function(j) list(a=a(j), b=b(j)))`